# Aligning form control inline with bootstrap and Syncfusion widget

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, syncfusion

I'm trying to align the **syncfusion js widget**, a dropdownlist, to display it **inline** with the label.
I'm using bootstrap 3.

I'm not able to align them in a nice way, I mean **align the middle of the label perfectly to the middle of the dropdownlist**.

It seems like it's a problem of the syncfusion widget.

here is the working code snippet:
http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/ciavymzk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cssClass](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejdropdownlist#members:cssclass) property in DropDownList control to set the Bootstrap’s *“form-group”* class. Once the DropDownList control is rendered the input element will be made hidden, hence adding *“form-group”* to the input element directly will not work. Check the updated [JSPlayground sample](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/vu1ng4r4).